# Install Ubuntu together with Windows 8

Tags: dual-boot

I have a desk top Hp 18-5010Ia (bought in 2015) Procesador Intel (R) Celeron CPU J1800@2.41 GHz; which came with Windows 8 already installed. I want to have Ubuntu 16 in this machine and be able to use both OS. 
I followed instructions from Ubuntu page to install the program and be able to start Ubuntu from a USB memory pencil. 
However when I switch the computer off and restart again it always go to Windows and if I move to Ubuntu (via Esc and F9)I have to start Ubuntu installation from scratch.
Is there an easy way to solve this problems; I have been looking to some help pages but looks to complicated to me, using a language I cant really understand.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you been installed the boot loader into MBR? try to install it into your primary Hard-drive. It should available when configuring partition of OS.

Answer (score 0):

Have you check the UEFI and CMOS configuration on your BIOS. You should check once you have installed Ubuntu, that you configured start from HDD and not from USB stick again and again, before the first auto restart while ubuntu is installing